# Capistrano 3: "NoMethodError: undefined method `server' for main:Object" during rake assets: precompile

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, rbenv, capistrano3

I'm deploying a Rails 4 application using Capistrano 3, to a remote server on digital ocean. I've been debugging the process but hit a wall during a rake: assets precompile task.

The error message is:

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `server' for main:Object
/home/user_name/apps/project_name/releases/20151123210909/config/environments/production.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

The specific code on that line in the production.rb file is:

```
server '159.203.22.61', user: 'user_name', roles: %w{web app}
```

I followed this [link](http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/deploy-rails-apps-with-capistrano) and setup the production.rb file and the only line I added in that file gave me an error. I've used a bit of Capistrano 2 in a previous project but it looks like Capistrano 3 has a lot of changes and it doesn't quite work like its previous version? I read that the project is deployed after all of the rake tasks are finished so I think the deploy.rb file is not the problem. Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: this should be in `config/deploy/production.rb` not `config/environments/production.rb`. That being said you probably cleared out a lot of important Rails configurations from `config/environments/production.rb`

Comment: Did I modify the incorrect production.rb file? I will revert my changes and report back! I just noticed there were 2 production.rb files....

Comment: That seemed to fix it! thank you

Comment: Also, should `server '159.203.22.61,'` be `server: '159.203.22.61,`?

Comment: No problem I can understand the confusion. @AdrianMann the syntax is fine it was the file it was used in that was the issue.